# Automate GeoPackage opening

Tags: pyqgis, geopackage

I created a GeoPackage file containing some layers and I'm trying to automate its opening, however a message box appears asking which layers should be added. I will attach an image.

Is there a way to improve this opening by automating the addition of all GeoPackage layers?

[image]

Comment: I believe that if GeoPackage contains only one table it will be opened automatically. Do you want that all the layers would be added automatically, even there may be tens or hundreds? If you created the data yourself, maybe you could save the project for fast re-opening?

Comment: In future, please add a code attempt to your question as formatted text, not in an image.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way (layers will be loaded in alphabetical order):

*Assuming all layers inside the GeoPackage are vector type.

```
from osgeo import ogr

path = r'C:\Users\Aloísio\Desktop\auxiliar\rede.gpkg'

sub_lyr_names = [l.GetName() for l in ogr.Open(path)]
for lyr_name in sorted(sub_lyr_names, reverse=True):
    vl = QgsVectorLayer(f'{path}|layername={lyr_name}', lyr_name, 'ogr')
    if vl.isValid():
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```